# The LinkButton text is not displayed

Tags: asp.net

I have a web form and I added `LinkButton` in `Page_Load` like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Parent <ul>
            HtmlGenericControl ul = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
            pnl1.Controls.Add(ul);
            for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                HtmlGenericControl parentli = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
                LinkButton parentlnk = new LinkButton();
                parentli.Controls.Add(parentlnk);
                parentlnk.ID = "lnkparent" + i.ToString();
                parentlnk.Text = "Parent link" + i.ToString();
                ul.Controls.Add(parentli);                    

                //Child <ul>
                HtmlGenericControl childul = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
                parentlnk.Controls.Add(childul);

                HtmlGenericControl childli = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
                childul.Controls.Add(childli);

                LinkButton childlk = new LinkButton();
                childlk.ID = "lnkchild" + i.ToString();
                childlk.Text = "link_child" + i.ToString();
                childli.Controls.Add(childlk);
            }
        }
```

But **Output** is:

[image: link]

The correct page should be like this:

[image: Correct link]

I tested `parentlnk.Attributesa.add("Text","Parent link")` or `parentlnk.Attributesa.add("Value","Parent link")` but they did not work properly.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: create your control with all its attributes set & then add to the control collection. this should solve your issue..

Comment: I do't need to define all attributes. Child link work properly but I defined it like the parent link.

Comment: by all I meant only those which you are defining. What i mean is add the control only after the properties are set

Answer (score 0):

using these two lines together is your problem

```
parentlnk.Text = "Parent link" + i.ToString();
parentlnk.Controls.Add(childul);
```

when you add controls to parentlnk, it will delete whatever you set in Text.

what you need to do is create a Label class and add it as a controller to parentlnk

Comment: Thanks for response. If we assume in my scenario `parentlnk.Text` isn't displayed by `parentlnk.Controls.Add(childul)`, I can never set `parentlnk.Text`. But I've set it by `((LinkButton)pnl1.FindControl(parentlnk.ID)).Text = "Parent Text";`

Comment: I didn't understand you completly. did my answer work?

Comment: I solved this problem by replace `parentlnk.Controls.Add(childul)` with `parentli.Controls.Add(childul)`. I am looking for why I can set `parentlnk.Text` by `FindControl` but I can't set in `parentlnk.Text = "Parent link" + i.ToString();`??